# Getting a NoMethodError in #new, "undefined method 'posts' for nil:NilClass" when creating a new instance of a model that belongs to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding a new model to my app, basically a Forum which will have posts. Posts belongs_to Forums.

When writing the new page for my Posts, I have this:  (I'm using HAML, thats why it looks maybe a bit weird)

```
= form_for(model: [@forum, @post], local: true) do |form|
  .form-group
    .col-sm-2.control-label
      = form.label :title
    .col-sm-12
      = form.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Title of post", autofocus: true
  .form-group
    .col-sm-2.control-label
      = form.label :description
    .col-sm-12
      = form.text_area :description, rows: 8, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Body of post"
  .form-group
    .col-sm-12
      = form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
```

I had form_for(model: @post) and that also didn't work.
When it tries to create a Post, we get this error

```
NoMethodError in Posts#new
undefined method `model_name' for #<Hash:0x00007f801c9d39d0>
```

and it highlight's this line

```
= form_for(model: [@forum, @post], local: true) do |form|
```

I don't know why this is happening and none of the similar fixes work for me. Here is my posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:edit, :show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_user, except: [:index, :show]

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @post = @forum.posts.create(post_params)
  @post.user = current_user
  if @post.save then
     redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to(forums_path)
end

private
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title)
  end

end
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: Somewhere using Posts instead of Post.Let me know where have you made this error (if any)

Comment: Post belongs to Forum but what association does Forum has to Post. What is bothering me is 
```
@post = @forum.posts.create(post_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing [`form_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) and [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with).

`form_with` with was introduced in Rails 5 to replace `form_for` and `form_tag` which had different signatures.

The signature of `form_for` is `form_for(record, options = {}, &block)`. Which means that these are equivalent:

```
form_for([@forum, @post])
form_with(model: [@forum, @post], local: true)
```

This also explains the error message:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#new
undefined method `model_name' for #<Hash:0x00007f801c9d39d0>
```

As you are passing a hash as the first argument to `form_for`.